# Unexpected Token in Rust Macro

Tags: rust

I am trying to write a macro that expands to a collection of `impls` for some custom structs I'm writing. This is what I have:

```
pub trait ComponentWise : Clone + Copy {
  fn new(x: f32, y: f32, z: f32) -> Self;
  
  fn x(&self) -> f32;
  fn y(&self) -> f32;
  fn z(&self) -> f32;

  fn has_nans(&self) -> bool {
    f32::is_nan(self.x()) || 
    f32::is_nan(self.y()) || 
    f32::is_nan(self.z())
  }
}

macro_rules! component_wise_impls { 
  ($T:ty) => {
    impl ComponentWise for $T {
      fn new(x: f32, y: f32, z: f32) -> $T {
        let x: $T = $T { vals: [x, y, z] };
        debug_assert!(!x.has_nans());
        x
      }
   };
}

pub struct Vector {
  pub vals: [f32; 3]
}

component_wise_impls!(Vector);
```

Sadly, I'm being told:

> error: unexpected token: Vector
>
> let x: $T = $T { vals: [x, y, z] };

I'm a little surprised, since I can do `Vector { vals: [x, y, z] }`, and I would think that is exactly what `$T { vals: [x, y, z] };` expands to. Is there a way of writing this `new` function in a macro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is working:

```
macro_rules! component_wise_impls {
    ($T:ident) => {
        impl ComponentWise for $T {
            fn new(x: f32, y: f32, z: f32) -> $T {
                let x: $T = $T { vals: [x, y, z] };
                debug_assert!(!x.has_nans());
                x
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You cannot use a `ty` where an expression is needed.

From this [page](http://smallcultfollowing.com/rust-int-variations/imem-umem/guide-macros.html#interpolation-location):

> The interpolation `$argument_name` may appear in any location consistent with its fragment specifier (i.e., if it is specified as `ident`, it may be used anywhere an identifier is permitted).

As llogiq pointed out, you have to implement the `x`, `y` and `z` methods, so the complete code is:

```
pub trait ComponentWise : Clone + Copy {
  fn new(x: f32, y: f32, z: f32) -> Self;

  fn x(&self) -> f32;
  fn y(&self) -> f32;
  fn z(&self) -> f32;

  fn has_nans(&self) -> bool {
    f32::is_nan(self.x()) || 
    f32::is_nan(self.y()) || 
    f32::is_nan(self.z())
  }
}

macro_rules! component_wise_impls {
    ($T:ident) => {
        impl ComponentWise for $T {
            fn new(x: f32, y: f32, z: f32) -> $T {
                let x: $T = $T { vals: [x, y, z] };
                debug_assert!(!x.has_nans());
                x
            }

            fn x(&self) -> f32 {
                self.vals[0]
            }

            fn y(&self) -> f32 {
                self.vals[1]
            }

            fn z(&self) -> f32 {
                self.vals[2]
            }
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Vector {
  pub vals: [f32; 3]
}

component_wise_impls!(Vector);
```

Comment: @anjruu: You also have to implement the `x/y/z()` functions and make `Vector` implement `Copy` and `Clone` for this to work.